# Wrong popup size in listview with section index

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

I have a listview with fast scroll and section index. I'm using dates as section header. It works fine on a nexus 4, but in a samgung device, the popup doesn't resize to suit the text. The image below shows the problem:

[image: Error listiview fast scroll and section header]

This is the declaration of the listview in my xml:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:divider="@color/grismedio"
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: please paste your xml and code files for better understanding of your problem.